# Scatterplot gene coexpression with 2 variables on X and Y

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot, rna-seq

I have a matrix with 2 variables ( A and B), 
and the expression of two genes which I would like to plot in relationship to this variables.

Data:

```
A = c(1.16, 1.16,   0.96,   0.96,   0.96,   0.67,   0.67,   0.67,   0.78,   0.78,   0.55,   0.3,    0.3,    0.3,    0.26,   0.26,   0.26)
B = c(6.513421667,  6.513421667,    4.981984615,    4.981984615,    4.981984615,    2.858295,   2.858295,   2.858295,   3.19875,    3.19875,    3.604918,   10.82963857,    10.82963857,    10.82963857,    8.607186667,    8.607186667,    8.607186667)
gene1 = c(0.007614672,  0.007632451,    0.007066506,    0.007524053,    0.008337992,    0.012520277,    0.012249,   0.011351902,    0.01263021, 0.009969673,    0.008850031,    0.007290232,    0.00724349, 0.007161781,    0.004299581,    0.004896156,    0.005970637)
gene2 = c(0.019649471,  0.015339387,    0.0180094,  0.018787749,    0.014556951,    0.011603994,    0.012012431,    0.011189356,    0.012666218,    0.01472512, 0.016299402,    0.017398006,    0.021602747,    0.019780361,    0.014182726,    0.015611876,    0.018550423)
```

This is what I have done:

```
df = data.frame(A, B, gene1, gene2)
df <- data.frame(A = rep(A, 3), B= rep(B, 3), y = c(gene1, gene2), genes = rep(c("gene1", "gene2", each = 17))
plot(A,B, pch=unclass(genes))  # different symbol
legend("bottomright", legend=levels(genes), pch=c(1:3))
```

I would like to plot the genes on the graph so they correspond to variable A (x-axis) and variable B (y-axis) and so it would look something like this Thanks!:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ecg, for every gene1 and gene2 value, they would have the same A and B values. And I notice you have duplicate A and B values as well.. How would you visualize the values under gene1 and gene2 ? By the color of the points?

Comment: Yes, @StupidWolf
- For every gene1 and gene2 values, they would have the same A and B values
- The repeated values of A and of B aren't duplicates but "replicates".
- Color of the points/ shape to compare to a legend

Comment: Hey I don't think you can see any difference, not posting as an answer yet because I am not sure how you want to visualize it. let's say you do df <- data.frame(A,B,value = c(gene1, gene2), 
genes = rep(c("gene1", "gene2"), each = length(gene1)))

Comment: ggplot(df,aes(x=A,y=B,shape=genes,col=value))+geom_jitter(width=0.05) + scale_color_viridis_c()

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf ! I will work from here :)

Comment: Hey @StupidWolf could it be that instead of plotting by a color scale/palette we could plot it so the higher the value, the bigger the datapoint? SO it will be easier to identify when the expression is higher because the size of the dot will be bigger. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: yes you can try that, size = value?

Comment: @StupidWolf it works, but the problem is that one gene is on values ~ 0.007 and the other is ~0.01 therefore gene2 is always showing bigger. Is there a way of setting up the radius/size of the points for each gene? The aim is to show that the biggest expression of one gene is under certain conditions, and the other gene under other conditions.